# Can't enter Goldenglow sewer in Thieves guild quest "Loud and Clear"

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I started the thieves guild questline a while back on PC. I got to the quest called "Loud and Clear" when you need to get into Goldenglow Estate but the only way I know how to get in is through the sewer but the prompt to enter goldenglow sewer doesn't show and I can't get in. Is there another way in or maybe a console command to help me get in?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

To get the way point to enter via the sewers, you need to speak to Vex.

[Source](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Loud_and_Clear)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the journal entry or the quest marker to get in through the sewer entrance, you only need to find it. If you swim to the island from the north (the grumpy Dark Elf farmer whatsisname's farm) and look for a place where you can scramble up, the sewer entrance is near a kind of boardwalk. Failing that, and if your sneak & lockpicking skills are good enough, you could get in through the front door.

Answer (score 0):

You can also enter from the main door, but it is harder. You have to kill all the enemies and then climb over the bridge to the main entrance. I hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can either talk to Vex to learn the secret location, go through the front door, or parkour from the water onto the land. There are several barely usable points which you can jump onto the island from, with the one I used last time I played the quest being present here:

[image: sneakz]
It requires some navigation through the wood to find where collision is, though.

Answer (score -3):

you cannot get in from the sewer you first have to kill everyone in front of the house then go in though the front door and kill everyone inside. once you have done that you can either find the safe in the house and lockpick it or find the person with the key. once it is unlocked you can then take whats inside and leave from the sewer and go back to the guild. P.S if you haven't already you have to burn down three bee hives that are located outside of the house otherwise you won't finish the quest.

Answer (score -4):

I don't think can go through the sewers to get into goldenglow estate Cause when u get in u use the sewers to get out. U can pick the back door or just kill all the enemies and use through the front door.